# jQuery works on my page, but firebug says $ is not defined error. Why and how to avoid it?

Tags: jquery, html

UPDATE: Finally I found the solution, it was totally my fake. There were an iframe tag on the site, and in the external file I didn't include jQuery.
But I learned a lot from your answer and checked my code a lot of time. :)
update END.

Firebug console issues the following error message:
$ is not defined
ajaxlib.js()ajaxlib.js (line 6)
[break on this error] $(document).ready(function()

But jQuery works perfectly on my page.
I include the jQuery source in the first script tag (it was the most commonly suggested solution), so it's should be loaded.

Any help appreciated.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/advexpad_lib.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxlib.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/highlight.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you getting this error on page load or through page interaction? Or are you getting it when running commands in the Firebug console? If the latter, try using `window.$` or `window.jQuery`. Firebug seems to flip out and lose scope for me a lot and can't seem to remember that it's supposed to scan the scope chain and find $ up at window.

Comment: Getting on page load, and not running commands in the console.

Comment: Interestingly, if I insert an alert('') directly after the $(document).ready(function() the errors messages gone... 
also, I commented out the latest addig code sequence from my js file, but that isn't helped too.

Comment: check the `jQuery.noConflict()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ it helps preventing "clashes" between JS libraries and may solve this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing all $ characters with "jQuery". They are possibly conflicting with an other library you are including.

as in;

```
$(document).ready(function() {} );
```

to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {} );
```

Comment: Tried, but not helped. :(
now firebug says: jQuery is not defined,

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to use jQuery, vs. where you include the jQuery script? If you're trying to use jQuery before you include the jQuery library, that might be causing the problem.

Comment: I understand, but this is not the situation. I try to use jQuery in ajaxlib.js and you can see above, it comes after the js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js with two lines.
The error seems to my, that jQuery cannot loaded in time. If I stop the error with firebug, in the jQuery object properties (or attributes) the active prop's value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, the problem is in the 3rd script.  Try moving the second script below the 3rd one.  The advexpad maybe overwriting the $ shortcut in their module.  Also including jquery first isn't recommended, but rather required in your case.  Since the 3rd script uses it, you have to have it precede it.

Comment: Tried this also, and doesn't count. :(
Both ajaxlib.js and advexpad_lib.js developed by our company and not interfere with jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried running your files through jslint.com to check for errors?

Comment: I doubt it is timing, because it will block until it is loaded since you defined it first. I really think you have sone syntax issue where ff is not as tolerant causing the file to not evaluate correctly.