# jQuery ajax $ is not defined but execute properly anyway?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, error-handling, undefined

Firebug is giving me an error stating that "$ is not defined (70 out of range 28)"

I don't understand why since the code executes fine anyway. The code looks for a div with class "like" that when clicked, sends values to ajax. Here is the relevant code:

```
<div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>-inside" class="inside">
            <div id="like_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="like" style="position:absolute; right: 2.5em;">
                <a id="likebtn_<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="likeimgoff" href="#"><span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    likestatus = 1;
    dislikestatus = 1;

    $(document).on("click", ".like", function(){
        postID = $(this).attr('id').replace('like_', '');
```

The specific line in question is this:

```
postID = $(this).attr('id').replace('like_', '');
```

The postID variable is indeed being assigned the proper value so I don't understand the reasoning for the error. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Do you have sample page, where we can see your problem in action?

Comment: Agreed. If the issue is happening with an ajax call (doesn't appear in the sample), that part of the code is key to understanding the problem.

Comment: The ajax call is way further down the code and I know it isn't part of the problem (it worked before without problem).

Answer (score 0):

They might be conflicting libraries, such as Prototype etc. As noted here: [jQuery works on my page, but firebug says $ is not defined error. Why and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265667/jquery-works-on-my-page-but-firebug-says-is-not-defined-error-why-and-how-to)

Try changing $ to jquery like: `jQuery(document).ready(...`

Also, double-check that your script there comes *after* the `<script>` line where jquery is being loaded.

Comment: After giving it a few minutes, the error has disappeared. I haven't done anything to the code to fix it though. Odd indeed.